# JS alert doesn't fire after php update

Tags: javascript

1. The alert message 'Test' fires on load correctly.
2. The tblRoles table is updated correctly after the button is clicked.
   HOWEVER
3. The  alert message 'Update' does not fire after the update/button click.

Code:

```
  <?php 

    //works correctly--On load----------------

    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
    alert("Test"); 

    </script>';

 //works correctly------------------

if (($_GET["Action"])=='edit')
{   
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE tblRoles SET Role='" .$_GET["strA"] ."',Test='".$_GET["strA"] ."' WHERE ROLEID= " . $_GET["ID"]);   

    //does not work------------------

    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 

    alert("Update"); 

    </script>';

}?>

<input class="grid" type="text" id="?php echo($row[1]);?>" 
onblur="UpdateDiv('grid','edit','<?php echo $row[0]?>',document.getElementById('<?php  echo($row[1]);?>').value)",
value="<?php echo($row[1]);?>" size="20"  maxlength="20" />
```

Comment: You're missing some HTML & some javascript for us to be able to answer this for you.

Comment: Does the HTML under the javascript (the form elements) get output? I assure you - this is not caused by the database update itself.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the php script in a browser. Does the script tag that calls "`alert("Update")`" show up when you view the page's source after it loads? If it doesn't, then the problem is probably server-sided.